# Microsoft Teams Integrate Files tab with Custom App tab

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-teams

I have developed integration of Custom Tabs App (as an external web service) into Microsoft Teams: [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/what-are-tabs?view=msteams-client-js-latest)

I need to implement possibility to open files from Files tab of Channel/Group chat in this Custom Tab app.
Also it should be great also to have ability to open files in Custom Tabs App directly from attachments menu: [image: Context menu of Attachment]

Thanks in advance for any response.

Answer (score 0):

Currently You cannot add an ability that will provide an option to deep -link for the file to custom tab of your app. This is by design.

Comment: I've found the request that is made by MS Teams when the Files tab is being loaded:

`Request URL: https://us-prod.asyncgw.teams.microsoft.com/msgsearch/v1/query`
`Request Method: POST`
`Body: {"OPTION":{"RESULTBASE":0,"RESULTCOUNT":50},"QUERYSTRING":{"and":[{"ThreadId":"19:1dc26870bfb04555b7749eebfbbbb089@thread.v2"},{"Annotation":{"TYPE":"files"}},{"not":{"Annotation":{"TYPE":"files","VALUE":{"fileType":"deeplink"}}}}]}}`
Headers:
...
`X-Skypetoken: <skypeToken>`

But we need 2 things here:
- The correct request URL (seems like it is generated)
- We need a way to get skypeToken.

Comment: You can generate a deep-link to file in the files tab, but you cannot generate the deep-link to file located in personal tab. Here is the format  to deep-link to file in files tab:

Comment: Here is the format to Deeplink to file in channel:
This is the serialization of this object:
{
tenantId: “72f988bf-86f1-41af-91ab-2d7cd011db47”,
filetype: = “pptx”,
objectUrl: “https://microsoft.sharepoint.com/teams/ActionPlatform/Shared Documents/FC7- Bot and Action Infra/Kaizala Actions in Adaptive Cards - Deck.pptx”,
baseUrl: “https://microsoft.sharepoint.com/teams/ActionPlatform”,
serviceName: “teams”,
threadId: = “19:f8fbfc4d89e24ef5b3b8692538cebeb7@thread.skype”,
groupId: “ae063b79-5315-4ddb-ba70-27328ba6c31e”
}